# How to define an inner margin for a tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I created a poster with the *baposter* class. The basic structure is defined through *posterbox* objects. Within these, I did embed pictures, using *tcolorbox* as frame.

Actual Code:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=gray,colback=white,boxrule=2pt,arc=0.6em,boxsep=-1mm]
\includegraphics[width=5.8cm]{figure.eps}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{article}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=gray,colback=white,boxrule=2pt,arc=0.6em,boxsep=-1mm]

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

I did realize that the embedded image protrudes the rounded corners. How can I apply something like an inner margin? I did play with the boxsep argument, which did not seem to help.

Sorry for not providing the complete file. I would have to strip quite a lot, since the poster contains a lot of unpublished data.

[image: rendering problem or user error?]

Edit: Sorry for not providing an image! MWE also included now.
Also happens for empty tcolorboxes.

---

This portion added by Steven Segletes to better demonstrate the strange behavior.  Changing the `arc` units from `em` to `pt` changes the behavior completely.

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=gray,colback=white,boxrule=2pt,arc=.3em,boxsep=-1mm]

\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=gray,colback=white,boxrule=2pt,arc=3.4pt,boxsep=-1mm]

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try to use the `left=`, `right=` etc. options, with some length arguments. The `boxsep` option acts in addition to them

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. left/right= seems to shift e.g. text within the tcolorbox, but the embedded image remains in its place.

Comment: Perhaps your image is too large? ;-)

Comment: I just did resize the picture, but the problem with the frame persists.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It appears to be an interaction of `boxrule` and `arc`.  The rule must be thick enough, or the arc radius small enough, to avoid the arc'ed corner getting clipped by the rectangular text box.

Comment: Interestingly, if you specify `arc` in `pt` instead of `em`, all seems well.  Very strange.

Comment: I edited your question to add this interesting effect.  I hope you don't mind :^)

Comment: Thanks a lot! (Would I have enough reputation, I would reward your comment.)

Comment: I think it's some kind of bug in `tcolorbox`. If `boxrule` is defined with `em` units, it's not drawn at all. Maybe no default font is defined to be used as reference for `em` or `ex` and the result is 0.

Comment: Thank you so much for this question, for some weird reason my google fu was not on my side today for a good 10 minutes...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is more than one question to answer here. I try to answer them step by step.

**1. How to define an inner margin for a tcolorbox?**

The margins are set by `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`. Additionally, `boxsep` is added to all these values for the resulting margin.

E.g.

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=1pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]...
```

gives a total of `3pt` for the left and right margin, and a total of `1pt` for the top and bottom margin.

**2. Content clipping**

If rounded corners are used, but there is *no* margin or a very small margin, the text content (e.g. a picture) can protrude over the rounded corners. This can be avoided by using the `enhanced` and `clip upper` options of the `skins` library which clip the interior:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced,clip upper,%<------------
  colframe=gray,colback=white,boxrule=2pt,arc=10pt,
  boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**3. Font dependend units**

A `tcolorbox` is drawn inside a `pgfpicture` or a `tikzpicture` environment. Inside such an environment, a nullfont is used. If font dependend units like `arc=.3em` are given, the actual sizing depends on where this setting is used exactly inside the internal implementation. If it is used (and expanded) before the actual `tikzpicture`, it will have the intended size, but if it is used very lately in the drawing process, it may become zero.

Using

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0.3em]

\end{tcolorbox}
```

gives an unlucky combination of this effect. The `outer arc` is computed automatically *before* the graphical environment is started. It gets the intended (expanded) size. The inner arc (i.e. `arc`) stays at `0.3em` and becomes `0pt` inside the graphical environment.

So, currently, one should use fixed units like `3pt` or `3mm` to avoid such effects. But, for the next `tcolorbox` version (`3.36` or higher), I will implement a *sanitize* procedure which freezes font depended units before entering the graphical environment.

Comment: @AboAmmar Thank you :-) Meanwhile, the sanitize procedure for font dependend units is implemented in the current version `3.40`.

Comment: What are the default values for `top`/`bottom` and `left`/`right`?

Comment: @Matt Documented in Section 4.7.4 "Spacing" from page 39. `top`/`bottom` are 2mm, `left`/`right` are 4mm.